# Java check for duplicates into bidimensional map

Tags: java, hashmap, compare, keyvaluepair, key-pair

I want to know how to check for duplicates into bidimensional map.
The issue is about this sample code

```
        Pair<Integer, String> pair1 = new Pair<Integer, String>();
        pair1.First = 1;
        pair1.Second = "A";

        Pair<Integer, String> pair2 = new Pair<Integer, String>();
        pair2.First = 1;
        pair2.Second = "A";

        Map<Pair<Integer, String>, Double> map 
                              = new HashMap<Pair<Integer,String>, Double>();
        map.put(pair1, 0.0);

        System.out.println(map.keySet().contains(pair2));
        System.out.println(map.containsKey(pair2));
        System.out.println(map.get(pair2)!=null);
```

why is the output:

```
false
false
false
```

?
How can I check for duplicates? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you post the code for your Pair class?  I suspect it's not overriding equals and hashcode()

Comment: import com.sun.star.beans.Pair;

Comment: Hmn.  I can't seem to find the source for that.  Can you view it and see if it overrides equals() and hashCode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect your pair class doesn't define `equals()` and `hashCode()` correctly.

If `Pair` is defined like this:

```
public class Pair<T, U>{
    T First;
    U Second;
}
```

Then you'll see the results your getting.  By default java uses object identity as it's equality comparison, so two different pairs will be unequal even if they have the same contents.  You can override `equals` and `hashCode` in order to provide a more meaningful comparison.

```
public class Pair<T, U>{
    T First;
    U Second;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }

        Pair<?, ?> pair = (Pair<?, ?>) o;

        if (First != null ? !First.equals(pair.First) : pair.First != null) {
            return false;
        }
        return !(Second != null ? !Second.equals(pair.Second) : pair.Second != null);

    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = First != null ? First.hashCode() : 0;
        result = 31 * result + (Second != null ? Second.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }
}
```

This will produce when used with your code:

```
true
true
true
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you implicitly use method `pair1.equals(pair2)` comparison in `java.lang.Object` class. Which is defined:

`The equals method for class Object implements the most discriminating possible equivalence relation on objects; that is, for any non-null reference values x and y, this method returns true if and only if x and y refer to the same object (x == y has the value true).` (`Java 8 API`)

Since your `Pair` class does not override `.hashCode()` and `.equals(Object other)` methods => the comparison `x == y` return `false`.

This would work:

```
   public class NewClass {
static class Pair<I,S>{
    private I First;
    private S Second;

    @Override
    public int hashCode(){
        return First.hashCode() + 23*Second.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other){
        Pair<I, S> otherPair = (Pair<I, S>) other;
        return (this == null ? otherPair == null : (this.First == otherPair.First && this.Second == otherPair.Second));
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Pair<Integer, String> pair1 = new Pair<Integer, String>();
    pair1.First = 1;
    pair1.Second = "A";

    Pair<Integer, String> pair2 = new Pair<Integer, String>();
    pair2.First = 1;
    pair2.Second = "A";

    Map<Pair<Integer, String>, Double> map = new HashMap<Pair<Integer,String>, Double>();
    map.put(pair1, 0.0);

    System.out.println(pair1.equals(pair2));
    System.out.println(map.containsKey(pair2));
}
}
```